# How do I move Ubuntu 13.04 from real storage to VirtualBox?

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, backup, virtualization

I want to move my Ubuntu 13.04 into the **VirtualBox** storage. **Paragon Backup & Recovery** can prepare Windows for moving into virtual storage. But I cannot find any analogue for Linux.

Can you give me advice, please?

Comment: How do you have your Ubuntu 13.04 installation installed now? Try to be a lot more specific: partition size, partition type, dual boot (yes/no), etc. With specific details it's possible to provide some steps into converting the installation. If it's on a dedicated physical disk, then it's fairly easy.

Comment: The [question I closed this as a duplicate of](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34802/convert-my-physical-operating-system-to-a-virtualbox-disk) should still work. You may need to boot into a LiveCD/USB environment to mirror the disk accurately and save that to the Windows disk (which you'll need to mount before running the `dd` command) but then you can just convert the raw image to a VDI once you're in Windows.

Comment: Also: doesn't VirtualBox allow mounting real partitions as virtual disks? If it does, wouldn't that be better? Edit: see http://www.sysprobs.com/access-physical-disk-virtualbox-desktop-virtualization-software

Comment: Sure, VirtualBox can use a real partition: http://askubuntu.com/a/192371/3940